# Editing with Coda

Tags: php, html, text-editor, markup, coda

I use coda as my text editor/subversion client at the studio I work at. We have many clients who hire us for a redesign of existing websites, meaning we have to stick with their existing file extensions. While I don't have to have an auto complete or color-coder for my PHP (and I write the majority of my code in separate files that are just included in the .html) It would be nice to be able to use it in .html files.

Is there any way to switch between how Coda interprets the file I am looking at, so that I can use auto-complete and the other features for PHP in an HTML file, or is there a plugin that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add a "custom syntax mode" in the Coda preferences to edit files with the "html" extension using "PHP-HTML" syntax highlighting.

Comment: Excellent, you nailed it. Thanks a ton!